# Conversion of constrained generic params from subtype to supertype

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, .net-4.5

I have a generic function like this:

```
private LOCAL_TYPE RemoteToLocal<LOCAL_TYPE>(RemoteObjectBaseType remoteObject)
        where LOCAL_TYPE: EntityBase
    {
        Type t = typeof(LOCAL_TYPE);
        if (t == typeof(FavoritePlace))
        {
            return new FavoritePlace(remoteObject as RemotePlaceType1);
        }
    }
```

Where `EntityBase` is non-abstract class. `FavoritePlace` class is inherited from `EntityBase`.

However, I'm getting an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type Common.Model.FavoritePlace to 'LOCAL_TYPE'.

That makes me wonder: FavoritePlace is a child of EntityBase, and LOCAL_TYPE is constrained to be of type EntityBase. Why cannot the conversion happen? I'm probably missing something important here.

**EDIT:** Okay, based on current answers and some experiment I've found another workaround, which is to do following conversion:

```
if (t == typeof(FavoritePlace))
    {
        return (LOCAL_TYPE)(EntityBase)new FavoritePlace(remoteObject);
    }
```

Now compiler is happy. But I'm just wondering, if such conversion is possible from compiler's perspective, why direct conversion to LOCAL_TYPE is not? Isn't *is convertible to* relationship transitive?

Comment: _Derived1_ inherits from _Base_, _Derived2_ inherits from _Base_. Then, can you convert _Derived1_ into _Derived2_?
In your example _Derived2_ is _LOCAL_TYPE_, _Derived1_ is _FavoritePlace_ and _Base_ is _EntityBase_.

Comment: The cast operator can actually perform few quite difference operations. It can safely cast to a base type (`FavoritePlace` → `EntityBase`) and it can also cast to a derived type (`EntityBase` → `LOCAL_TYPE`, this may throw an exception), but it can't cast from one subclass to another in one step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have established through *run-time code* that `LOCAL_TYPE` is in fact `FavoritePlace`, the compiler does not have the same knowledge *statically*. The compiler expects you to return an object of type `LOCAL_TYPE`, matching exactly the type parameter of the method.

Thinks of this situation: someone makes the following call -

```
var res = RemoteToLocal<MostHatedPlace>(remoteObj); // MostHatedPlace derives from EntityBase
```

Now you're inside `RemoteToLocal`, you go through some conditions, and now it's time to return the result. You call

```
return new FavoritePlace(remoteObject as RemotePlaceType1);
```

You know that this branch in code is impossible to reach, because there is a run-time check guarding you from that:

```
if (t == typeof(FavoritePlace)) {
    ....
}
```

However, the compiler must assume that reaching this return statement is possible, which would be an error in cases when `LOCAL_TYPE` is *not* a `FavoritePlace`.

You may want to reconsider the use of generics here: from the code snippet it appears that you  need the generic argument to avoid type-casting the result to the desired type in the caller. However, the caller would then need to perform an additional check to see if the conversion inside your `RemoteToLocal` has succeeded. In this case, a method

```
private EntityBase RemoteToLocal(RemoteObjectBaseType remoteObject) {
    ....
}
```

may be equally suited to the task, because it would be free of conversions that trick the compiler, and the structure of the calling code would remain the same.

Comment: Updated the question. And regarding use of generics: I need them to pass information about local type to the function, which is used to decide upon which branch of execution to take, so that correct local type will be constructed. However, you're right in the sense that return type doesn't have to be of that generic parameter, and could be just EntityBase. Then there are no problems with type conversion, obviously. Thanks for nice idea!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `FavoritePlace` is not necessarily the type of `LOCAL_TYPE`.
If you have

```
class OtherEntity : EntityBase { }
```

then you can't return `FavoritePlace` when calling

```
var entity = RemoteToLocal<OtherEntity>(remoteObject);
```

If you know the conversion is safe you can get around it with a cast:

```
return (LOCAL_TYPE)(object)new FavoritePlace(remoteObject as RemotePlaceType1);
```

Comment: I've accepted another answer because it showed how to get away from the problem at all, but your answer is also useful, so I give it +1. :)